# JavaScript, HTML - Is it possible to show value Html.TextAreaFor in Javascript ConfirmBox?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show Value of Html.TextAreaFor in Javascript Confirm Box but my code doesn't work. Maybe somebody has a good idea how to fix it..

This is my code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
           { %>
        <%= Html.Hidden("ThreadId", Html.Encode(this.Model.ThreadId))%>
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Quote,7,40,null)%>
        <br /> <button name="view" value="ViewQuoteButton" onclick="return ViewQuote()">
            View
        </button>
        <% } %>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        function ViewQuote() {

            if (confirm(document.valueOf( "here I'trying to show value of TextAreaFor"))) {

                return true;
            }
            else {
            } return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Thank you all and take care,
Ragims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("Quote").val();
```

OR

```
document.getElementByName("Quote").val();
```

Comment: if i do it like you say, happens postback, and javascript method is not called at all

Comment: can you confirm whether ViewQuote() is getting called at all? and since you are using MVC I strongly recomend you to use jQuery for your javascripts

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#view').click({
      alert($('#Quote').val(););     
        });
    });
</script>